# Inverse format currency symbol php

Tags: php, currency-formatting

So I am trying to inverse the value and the symbol that are being returned from:

```
 numfmt_format_currency($currencyFormatter, $value, $formatValue())
```

This code gives me:

```
 4$
```

And I want to inverse it like:

```
 $4
```

Not sure how to do it because the function must take all the parameters..
If anyone has some ideas I would appreciate it.

Comment: Do you have only dollar or any currency symbol?

Comment: I am anxiously having only euro symbol. "EUR".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define your proper [NumberFormat](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/numberformatter.create.php) and set your own pattern, here is an exemple :

```
<?php

$formatter = new NumberFormatter('us_US',  NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$formatter->setPattern('¤#,##0.00');
echo numfmt_format_currency($formatter, 4, 'USD');

?>
```

Result :

> $4.00

Answer (score 0):

You can use `number_format()` instead:

```
print '$' . number_format($value,2,'.',',');
```

[PHP Ref](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)